# What events are fired after user's click is handled?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, winforms, asynchronous

I handle user click on a button like:

```
 private void btnScanDirectory_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
 { 
     // some code
 }
```

What events are fired after `btnScanDirectory_Click()` finishes it's work ?

The reason I'm asking, that in `btnScanDirectory_Click()` I create a new `Thread()` in which I "fire and forget" `tree.BeginInvoke()` method that updates a `TreeView`.

So even when worker thread closes, the main thread is still handling those multiple `BeginInvoke()` calls, and when I access tree like

```
tree.ExpandAll();
```

in the same `btnScanDirectory_Click()` - it has no effect.

I couldn't find a way to "wait in main thread while all EndInvoke() methods are called", so I want to try `tree.ExpandAll()` in the event that fires **after** `btnScanDirectory_Click()` is finished.

Comment: Of course it can't have any effect, the tree starting filling *after* your Click handler completes.  ExpandAll() must be called only after the thread is done.  Trivially done with a BackgroundWorker.

Comment: @HansPassant I have to use only `Thread()` class... Can you help me how to do this without BackgroundWorker ?

Comment: What kind of nonsensical constraint is that?  Use the proper tools to get the job done.

Comment: @HansPassant thanks for voting minus for my question. Well done.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this page. It has the following details and I think this is what you're asking for: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.mouseclick.aspx

Depressing a mouse button when the cursor is over a control typically raises the following series of events from the control:

1. MouseDown event.
2. Click event.
3. MouseClick event.
4. MouseUp event.